# Chartboost SDK Swift Integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, chartboost

I have been trying to integrate the Objective C Chartboost SDK into a Swift project by following the tutorial on their site and adapting it to swift as best I know by using bridging headers etc. Unfortunately when I run the initial AppDelegate code I get a number of errors as seen in the following Screenshot

Image Link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIrBo.jpg

Then I tried putting @ signs before the strings like in Objective C and that brought a tonne of errors with it too, after a tonne of research I still didn't really find a way to fix this issue but these are the errors given when I try to add the @ sign in the following fashion.

```
Chartboost.startWithAppId(appId:@"appID", appSignature:@"appSig", delegate: self)
```

Image Link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtIuW.jpg

I also tried the following and was greeted with another similar error:

```
    let kChartboostAppID: NSString = "123"
    let kChartboostAppSignature: NSString = "123"
    Chartboost.startWithAppId(appId:kChartboostAppID, appSignature:kChartboostAppSignature, delegate: self)
```

But this gives me the following error (similar to the first error):

Cannot convert the expression's type '(appId: NSString, appSignature: NSString, delegate: AppDelegate)' to type '(String!, appSignature: String!, delegate: ChartboostDelegate!) -> Void'

I would be extremely grateful for any assistance as I have been trying to resolve this for a very long time:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me...

1. drop framework into supporting files
2. add to bridging header

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
   ```
3. Add chartboost delegate to appdelegate.swift

   ```
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, ChartboostDelegate {
   ```
4. in appldelegate didfinishlaunching

   ```
   let kChartboostAppID = "appid"
   let kChartboostAppSignature = "appsignature"
   Chartboost.startWithAppId(kChartboostAppID, appSignature: kChartboostAppSignature, delegate: self)
   Chartboost.setShouldRequestInterstitialsInFirstSession(false)
   ```
5. show ads

   ```
   Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocationHomeScreen)
   Chartboost.showInterstitial("AnyCusotmTitleID")
   ```